# Limit asp.net access based on time of day

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to limit an asp.net site to only be accessible between 8:00am and 5:00pm. If I add this to the Global.asax.cs file it works great. However at 5:00pm I get this page Server Error

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied. How can I redirect to an Error Page?

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {

        if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > System.TimeSpan.Parse("08:00:00") & DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < System.TimeSpan.Parse("17:06:00"))
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

    }




}
```

Just added this and it works

```
 public ActionResult ReleaseBulk() { if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > System.TimeSpan.Parse("08:00:00") & DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < System.TimeSpan.Parse("00:06:00")) { return View(); } else { return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error"); } }
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is just to address the error you are getting. This has nothing to do with making the site accessible for a specific time!.**

One way to do that is through IIS.

Open **IIS**, locate your site click **Error Pages**, which will open a new window, you should see the status codes with the associated error pages.

Since you are getting a **403** error, make sure to modify that to your custom error page.

[image]

Just out of curiosity. Why would you make the site only accessible at specific times? You sure know that is a server time and it can be different than client's time.

Comment: Its for my company and it we don't want users affecting database when we have certain Jobs running in MSSQL.

Comment: Is this application has its own application pool? If yes u could stop it. But it's also good to handle that error through IIS.

Comment: I ended up just adding this to each controller which was tedious , seems like there is a "better" way      public ActionResult ReleaseBulk()
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > System.TimeSpan.Parse("08:00:00") & DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < System.TimeSpan.Parse("00:06:00"))
            {
                return View();
            }
            else { return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error"); }
        }

Answer (score 1):

In your Global.asax add this line .

```
   void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if() //check your condition
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("your html file");
    }
```